# Unificar formatacao de coluna com iniciais

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, vba, formatação

Tenho uma coluna com iniciais de nomes que deveriam seguir um padrao de formatacao, como por exemplo:
Gustavo Silva => G S (Iniciais do nome + sobrenome, letras, separadas por espacos apenas)

Porem, tenho valores com inicias em diferentes formatacoes, como em alguns exemplos abaixo:
Gustavo Silva => G.S. / G. S. / GS / GS. / etc.

Existe alguma forma de unificar essa coluna para manter a formatacao que deveria estar sendo utilizada?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Podes criar uma tabela onde colocas os valores de entrada e saída, por exemplo

| G.S. | G S |
| --- | --- |
| GS. | G S |
| AM | A M |
| .... |  |

Na tua tabela, acrescentas uma nova coluna,por exemplo a seguir á coluna onde tens as iniciais "não formatadas", e usas um procv (em portugues de Portugal) ou vlookup (em inglês) para ir buscar o valor "formatado" da tabela de cima.

exemplo

```
Coluna XXX =procv("valor_nao_formatado", "tabela_de_entradas_saidas", 1,falso)
```